# When does Chrome autofill in a web page render?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, autofill

I have a customer who wanted their UI to display field names in a form (username field says "username", password field says "password", etc.). Since the form uses a password type `<input>` (which normally displays dots), I had to mock filling data into the fields by overlaying them with divs that contained the verbiage.

To recognize autofill, I wrote some Javascript that checks to see if the field is filled and acts accordingly (either hiding or showing the verbiage).

As far as I can tell, Chrome is the only browser that goes wonky. It doesn't seem to care if there's autofill data or not, and the verbiage always overlays the autofill data (ostensibly because the `hide` functionality isn't being triggered).

My long-winded question is When does Chrome autofill data in the rendering process? Does it wait until Javascript has finished as well? Is there any way for me to check if autofill data is occupying a field in Chrome?

Comment: If you put a long `setTimeout` on your verbiage hiding function, does it then process correctly on Chrome? That is to say, try to remove document loading order from the equation to determine if that is really what is throwing chrome off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to attach a listener to an event that activated the modal that contained the forms. Needless to say, this is a solution that would only work in my particular circumstances. I don't consider this an answer, but I'm posting it here to possibly give others looking for a solution a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

A simple workaround would be to use the [`placeholder`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-placeholder) attribute of HTML5, supported by WebKit and Firefox. It would take an extra bit of feature detection, but then you’d only have to implement the mock overlay in non-Chrome.

[Dive Into HTML5 explanation](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/forms.html#placeholder)

Comment: Though not widely supported, though this feature is one of the more awesome ones I'm looking for in HTML5

Comment: i. had. no. idea! BEGONE weighty labels with javascript focus and blur functions!!!!!!!!!!!